# What exactly is indicated by the blue "new activity" circle on the bookmarks page?

Tags: support, bookmarks

I was checking my bookmarks page and observed blue circles next to some of the questions:

[image]

Hovering over the circle shows the tool tip:

> This question has new activity

I checked the three blue questions, and the most recent activity on each ranged from 1.5 to 3 months, which doesn't seem very new. Additionally, I *know* I have visited the "bonus action spellcasting" question numerous times since it was last active. So it isn't at all clear to me what "new activity" means here.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but it could be removed answers or such. I'm fairly certain that those still trigger a notification.

Comment: @Matthieu The bonus action casting question has no removed answers.

Comment: Oh right, there's a permission level for seeing deleted answers! Can you also see deleted comments? If that's not the case, we can try to test that later.

Comment: @Matthieu No, deleted comments are mod only.

Comment: I tried making and deleting a comment on the 4th question in the list of your screenshot, does it make this blue notification appear for you? (the one about casting a spell through a magic item)

Comment: @Matthieu No, that didnt do anything.

Comment: I guess it was worth a try. I'm struggling to find anything else that wouldn't leave a trace. The only other thing I could think about is votes, but it wouldn't make much sense to make a notification for each time a vote is cast on a question or its answers.

Comment: Look to see if it's picking up when someone bookmarks the same questions, a few of mine looked like they had that. You'll need to go timeline > show vote summaries

Comment: "Additionally, I know I have visited the "bonus action spellcasting" question numerous times since it was last active." – When was the last time you visited this particular tab of your profile, though? I'm not sure the site takes anything else into account (other than when you last visited this page) in determining whether to display the blue dot. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: @V2Blast I don't visit it very often at all. Very well could be that "there is activity on these questions since you last visited the bookmarks page (that you may have already seen by navigating to them without coming to the bookmarks page)".